# Looping through my table, how do I know if the checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How I build my table:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var item = result[i];

    // Firma, BygningselementNavn, BrugerNavn, EmailAdresse, Telefon
    tbody = tbody + '<tr class="modtagerRow"><td>' + item.FirmaNavn + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + item.BygningselementNavn + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + item.BrugerNavn + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + item.EmailAdresse + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + item.Telefon + '</td>'
    // Medtag
    tbody = tbody + '<td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" 
            value="' + item.BygningselementId + '_' + item.BrugerId + '" 
            name="BygningsElementBrugerComboIds"></td>' + '</tr>';
}
$('#ModtagereTable tbody').append(tbody)
```

How I am trying to loop through the rows and adding a CSS class to rows that has it's checkbox checked.

1) I get the indexies to the console, but I can't make the if condition for all the checked checkboxes.

2) Also I am not sure if I can you `$( this )` or I should use something else, when adding the class `.hideForSendMailConfirm`?

```
// Looping rows in table
$( ".modtagerRow" ).each(function(index, element) {
    console.log('index: ' + index);
    // if
    if (element.checked) {
        $( this ).addClass(".hideForSendMailConfirm");
    }
});
```

Comment: The `.each()` loop is looping over each `".modtagerRow"` element, i.e., over each tr, so both `element` and `this` will refer to the tr...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.modtagerRow input:checked').closest('tr').addClass('hideForSendMailConfirm');
```

to add class to the rows that are not checked. You can use .not()

```
$('.modtagerRow input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').closest('tr').addClass('hideForSendMailConfirm');
```

Comment: +1: this is very similar to what I was going to post, but you beat me to it.

Comment: It worked, except that I actually want to add the class to all the rows that is NOT checked (my bad). How do I do that? I want to read up on this my self, but what do I search for when I want to know more about "input:checked"? Thanks

Comment: @radbyx i've updated the answer, you can use .not() you can find documentation for :checked here http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ and documentation for .not() is here http://api.jquery.com/not/ you can search jQuery selectors on google to find more

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
$(".modtagerRow").each(function (index, element) {
    if (element.checked) {
        $(this).addClass(".hideForSendMailConfirm");
    }
});
```

is actually looping through the table row having class `modtagerRow` and a table row does not have any `checked` property and hence your code is not working.

You can do something like this:

```
$(".modtagerRow :checkbox").each(function (index, element) {
    if (element.checked) {
        $(this).closest(".modtagerRow").addClass("hideForSendMailConfirm");
    }
});
```

This will loop through all the `checkbox` elements inside the table row and will check if it is checked or not and add the appropriate `hideForSendMailConfirm` class.

Also there is one more issue in your code:

```
.addClass(".hideForSendMailConfirm");
```

in order to add a class there is no need to add a `.` as prefix, we just pass the class name.

But again there is no need of looping here, you can just do this:

```
 $(".modtagerRow :checkbox:checked").closest('tr').addClass('hideForSendMailConfirm');
```

As, when we call methods of a jQuery object, the elements referred to by the selector we passed to `$()` are looped through automatically and implicitly. Therefore, we can usually avoid explicit iteration, such as a `each()` loop here.